# Partial inverse of the exponential map in differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a connected, geodesically complete Riemannian manifold. Let $p \in M$ and $\exp_p : T_pM \to M$ be the exponential map. Does there exists a dense subset $U \subseteq M$ containing $p$ and a smooth function $\log_p: U \to T_pM$ such that $\log_p(p) = 0$ and $\exp_p \circ \log_p$ is the identity on $U$?

How about the same question where "dense" is replaced with "$M \setminus U$ has measure zero in the Riemannian measure"?

If either/both turn out to be false, would compactness help?

---

I'm thinking of starting with a small neighborhood of $p$ and proceeding as in defining the logarithm in complex analysis, i.e., analytically continuing the map as far as possible, choose a branch if injectivity ever becomes an issue.

Possibly related question: [Riemannian Exponential Map is a Homeomorphism outside the Cut Locus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687852/riemannian-exponential-map-is-a-homeomorphism-outside-the-cut-locus)

If this result is standard or close to some textbook result, any reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the linked answer also answer this question since it states that the exponential is a diffeomorphism outside the cut locus?